# How to Show data labels on Extjs Column or Chart Graphs?

Tags: extjs, charts

How can I show or add Data Label on any graph like Coulmn or Line chart in Extjs.

Answer (score 1):

Work on this:
http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-extjs-charts.html

What label you want to add in special?

At http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/
navigate to ext, charts, there you see "labelFunction" which you can use to add your labels.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have seen & tried with given link by you. But don't get any solution.
Can you give me any Example of LabelFunction.

Comment: I have not much expirience with the chart so far, too. I followed this article to test it and it worked for me: http://aboutfrontend.com/2009/08/extjs-ext-chart-and-timeaxis/

Answer (score 0):

create text sprites for the title or any labels.

Look at the Ex.draw package.